# $.ajax() to $.getJSON()

Tags: ajax, getjson

I would like to ask if there is a method to parse data from `$.ajax()` to `$.getJSON()` please?

This is the `$.ajax()` example:

```
var apiUrl = 'https://api.com/url_here';
var apiKey = 1234567890;
var apiSecret = 0987654321;

var data = {};

$.ajax({
  url: apiUrl,
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(apiKey+ ":" + apiSecret)
  },
  data: data,
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'GET',

  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  },

  error: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

And this is what I have in my `$.getJSON()`, where I have a struggle in calling the `headers` for authentication:

```
    $.getJSON(apiUrl, function(json){

        console.log(JSON.stringify(json));

    });
```

Thanks a lot! xxx

Comment: This is exactly why `$.ajax` exists in the first place. To allow you to do things that `$.getJSON` and others don't support.

Comment: @Jon Ooooh okay,, so I assume there is no solution then?
Cheers x